# Highlights panel visible during record type selection

Tags: page-layout, service-cloud-console

I am able to see a blank highlights panel (or space) while creating a new case in the console.

The blank highlights panel is visible on both screens - selection of record type and the edit page while creating a new record type.

Ideally, the highlights panel shouldn't be shown while I create a new record in the console.

Image attached.
[image]

Anything that I am missing?

Thank you in advance.